# Swift NSTableView delegates not being called

Tags: swift, nstableview

I'm pulling in some RSS feeds and trying to display them in a NSTableView. I am getting data returned as expected but when I call reloadData() the delegates/datsource methods do not get called.

Here is my code:

```
...
myRSSReader.parseFeed(completed: {(arrResults:Array<Any>) in
    if let arrArticles = arrResults as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> {
        self.arrArticles = arrArticles
                                
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("Reloading table data...")
            self.tblArticles.reloadData()
        }
     }
})
```

The delegates are added to the viewcontroller

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
```

the tableview is connected

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblArticles: NSTableView!
```

and I am delegating them...

```
tblArticles.delegate = self
tblArticles.dataSource = self
```

but they are not being called and I can't see where my error is

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrArticles.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
 
    guard let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier:
        NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "ArticleCell"),
        owner: self) as? NSTableCellView
    else {
        return nil
    }
    
    //compile data
    var strArticle = ""
    if let dictThisArticle = arrArticles[row] as? Dictionary<String, Any>, let strTitle = dictThisArticle["title"] as? String, let strDescription = dictThisArticle["description"] as? String, let strLink =  dictThisArticle["link"] as? String {
        strArticle = "\(strTitle)\n\(strDescription)\n\(strLink)\n\n"
    }
 
    cellView.textField?.stringValue = strArticle
    return cellView
}
```

Tried calling it from viewDidLoad and same results.

Comment: Are you sure it’s not being called (have you verified with the debugger)? Could it be that’s it’s just always hitting the `return nil` path?

Comment: Does the documentation of `NSTableViewDataSource` say anything about required methods?

Comment: @alexander - I put a break point in numberOfRowsInSection, which should get called if everything is linked correctly, even if the datasource has 0 items. Breakpoint never gets hit.

Comment: @Willeke - I thought about that as well but wouldn't the build error if that was the case?

Comment: No, the required methods aren't required when Cocoa bindings are used.

Comment: Quick look at the documentation page says the two I have are required if no bindings are used, doesn't mention any other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

is a `UITableViewDataSource` method. The `NSTableViewDataSource` method is

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int
```

Comment: This is why I really wish there was an equivalent to `override` for checking that overrides of `@objc optional` methods are actually overrides

Comment: @Alexander: That has been suggested: https://forums.swift.org/t/pre-pitch-explicit-protocol-fulfilment-with-the-conformance-keyword/60246